# Trouble translating from Pandas to PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having alot of trouble translating a function that worked on a pandas DataFrame to a  PySpark UDF. Mainly, PySpark is throwing error that I don't really understand because it this is my first time using it. First, My dataset does contain some NaNs, which I didn't know would add some complexity to my task. With that said, the dataset contains the standard data types, i.e. categories and integers. Finally, I am running my algorithm using Pandas `groupby()` method, `apply()` to every row and using a lambda function I'm told that PySpark supports all these methods.

Now let me tell you about the algorithm. It's pretty much a counting game that I'm running on one column. and itself is written in vanilla python. The reason I'm saying this is because it's a bit too long to post. It returns three lists, i.e. arrays. Which from what I understand PySpark also supports. This is what a super short version of the algo looks like:

```py
def algo(x, col):
    # you will be looking at a specific pandas column --- pd.Series
    x = x[col]

    # LOGIC GOES HERE...

    return list1, list2, list3
```

I'm running the algorithm using:

```py
data = df.groupby("GROUPBY_THIS").apply(lambda x: algo(x, "COLUMN1"))
```

And everything is working fine. I'm returning the three lists of the correct length. Now when I try to run this algorithm using PySpark I'm confused on whether to use UDFs or PandasUDF. In addition, I'm throwing error that I can quite understand. Can someone point me in the correct direction here. Thanks!

```
Error:
ValueError: Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP.
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ValueError: Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP.